# good library to generate Detail Crash report for ios app?

Tags: ios, coding-style, app-store, crash-reports

Can anyone  suggest me what is the best way/procedure/library   to include in IOS app  before submitting to app store to  generate  detail Crash Report  , without compromising app efficiency.

is iTune  connect procedure is reliable ?? Can any one suggest me any good library ?

Comment: Compile with debugging information, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good overview of various libraries, I know Crittercism by reputation but it would be worth evaluating for yourself: http://www.jeremyfuller.net/2011/06/the-battle-of-the-ios-crash-reporters/

Comment: yeh very good blog Thnks. Will try that :) have u used any ??

Answer (score 0):

iTunes Connect has become more and more reliable as time goes on. Their current crash reports are doing the trick for us.
Flurry also has a way of catching exceptions that crash our applications, so that's useful too.